# javascript dialogbox without opening page

Tags: javascript, servlets

I have to display dialog box from servlet but without opening new window.

Below is code

```
PrintWriter printWriter =response.getWriter();
 String s ="<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>JavaScript Example</TITLE>"+
"<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JavaScript>"+
 "alert('File Uploaded');"+
 "</SCRIPT>"+
   "</HEAD>"+
  "</HTML>";
```

printWriter.print(s);

This code open dialog in new window but I want dialog in current window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand your problem. The posted code isn't opening a new window at all, it's just displaying an alert dialog. If you mean to say that it is opening a new window **and** then displaying the alert, then the problem rather lies in the calling code. Maybe you have a `target="_blank"` in the link or the form which is calling the servlet?

---

That said, generating view code in a servlet isn't always the best practice. JSP should be used for that.